# How to get blank cells as a Range in Epplus?

Tags: excel, vb.net, c#-4.0, range, epplus-4

I want to get all blank cells from a range using epplus 4 in Vb.net C#
Using Excel.Interop, i was using this:

```
Dim otherCells As ExcelRange = ExcelRangeV3.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks)
otherCells.Select()       
otherCells.FormulaR1C1 = "Other"
```

How can I do the same in Epplus 4 using either vb.net or c# code?
Any help is appreciated.